# Truecaller app not working in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, windows-8, windows-mobile

**Anyone who's still able to use truecaller services in their Windows phones?**

In W10M or even WP8.1?

I've W10M (15254.527) and I can download the app, but it gives "Unknown error!" just before the OTP. I am trying to get it work from sometime with no success. Anyone got it working in any WP8.1 or W10M?

*I tried resetting app data | re-installing the app | soft-reset.*

[image: Error Screenshot]

---

I am aware that "Truecaller Inc." has taken-off support for Windows devices. Its no longer available on Store. (But I managed to download it from QR code, just now).
[image: truecaller website]
[trucaller support page](https://support.truecaller.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000609729-Truedialer-Truemessenger-Truecaller-has-stopped-working-) | [Truecaller ends support](https://www.windowslatest.com/2018/06/25/truecaller-ends-support-for-its-windows-phone-app/) :/

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The app's not working on my wife's 930, and hasn't been for some time. I think TrueCaller dropped support for Windows Mobile a little while ago.

I've told her to use the built-in Blocked Calls feature whenever she gets a call from a scammer, but TrueCaller was great for this while it was still working.